# How to create an incrementing variable in Microsoft Access?

Tags: vba, ms-access, authentication, variables, ms-access-2010

In Microsoft Access, I am trying to create and incrementing variable so that I can lock the user out after 3 or so tries and I can't get it to work. Has anybody done  this before?? How would this be done (Global variables or something else)??

Please help, I have been trying for ages.

Cheers.

Comment: You say you have been trying for ages. Show us what you have tried and that you have put some efford into solving the prroblem yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like:

```
Public Function Attempts() As Integer

    Static Attempt As Integer

    Attempt = Attempt + 1

    Attempts = Attempt

End Function
```

Then:

```
If Attempts() <= 3 Then
    ' Allow login.
Else
    ' Block user.
End If
```